# How to customize login in django

Tags: python, django

I have a registration page for teachers having fields like email, mobile number, password etc, the table is named as Teacher.

I want to login page too for the same.

What I am doing is:

1. Added following in url page:

   ```
   url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'},name='login'),
   ```
2. Added following in settings.py:

   ```
   AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.Teacher'
   ```
3. Added login.html:

   ```
   {% extends "base.html" %}

   {% load widget_tweaks %}


   {% block body_block %}

   {% if form.errors %}

   <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
   {% endif %}

   {% if next %}
       {% if user.is_authenticated %}

           <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
           please login with an account that has access.</p>
       {% else %}
           <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
       {% endif %}
   {% endif %}

   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
               <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                   <div class="panel-heading">
                       <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                   </div>
                   <div class="panel-body">
                       <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
                           {% csrf_token %}

                           <p class="bs-component">
                               <table>
                                   <tr>
                                       <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
                                       <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                       <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
                                       <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
                                   </tr>
                               </table>
                           </p>
                           <p class="bs-component">
                               <center>
                                   <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" value="login" />
                               </center>
                           </p>
                           <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                       </form>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   {%endblock body_block%}
   ```

Now the login page doesn't work, giving me error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Teacher' has no attribute 'REQUIRED_FIELDS'
```

How can I implement custom login page in django?

Comment: what do your `model.py` and `views.py` look like?

Comment: model has basic definition of table, views.py doesn't have anything.

Comment: doesn't seem like your `models.py` is defining Teacher correctly. also, FYI the correct terminology for `Teacher` is not "table", but "model".